# How to serialize parameter with name 'OBJECT'

Tags: c#

I have the following data to serialize to use in a POST request to a webapi:

```
  var message = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { 
                sessionid = guid.ToString(), 
                personnelNumber = Environment.UserName, 
                name = user.DisplayName, 
                activity = Activity,
                object = Object, //object on left gets recognized as C# object
                time = DateTime.Now,
                timespan = TimeSpan});
```

All the parameters work okay except for the object one, which C# is thinking I mean a C# object. Is there a way to tell the serializer that is the name of the parameter rather than treat it as a C# object?

Comment: This doesn't actually have anything to do with JSON or serialization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `@` before object keyword like this.

```
  var message = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { 
                sessionid = guid.ToString(), 
                personnelNumber = Environment.UserName, 
                name = user.DisplayName, 
                activity = Activity,
                @object = Object,
                time = DateTime.Now,
                timespan = TimeSpan});
```